# How to override a method in Java, but still have partial functionality of the parent method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

This question was asked during job interview, Java Development, student position.

```
interface SomeInterface {
    public void execute();
}

class A implements SomeInterface {
    public void execute() {...}   
}
```

The question is:

New developer was asked to create a class that extends class A, and create method named `Execute`, this method will do some thing. How we should to rewrite the above code in order to have an output "start process" when method `Execute` is called
(of course the printing should not be done in class B).

```
class B extends A {
   public void execute() {
      //some code goes here 
   }
}
```

I know that it can be done with two functions and one of them is abstract.
Please advise...

Answer (score 10):

This is an example of the [template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_pattern). The abstract super Class A imposes the structure to processing by doing the "standard" parts - in this case printing something - and then invokes the concrete implementations of the subclass to do the actual/specific processing:

```
abstract class A implements someIterface {
   public void Execute() {
      System.out.println("start process"):
      doExecute();
   }

   protected abstract void doExecute();
}

class B extends A {
    protected void doExecute() {
        // some code goes here
    }
}
```

It would be more usual for:

- The method to be called `execute` instead of `Execute`
- The interface to be called `SomeInterface` instead of `someInterface`
- The interface to have the method `execute`

Comment: Isn't template method pattern??

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but the new developer in the question was asked to write **Execute** method in class B, in a way that when **Execute** will be called, "start process" should be print. Your solution do the same functionality but not as described in the terms. Any other ideas?

Comment: @UmNyobe Good call. Yes template pattern fits better than strategy pattern (although strategy kinda fits, it's a poor fit compared to template - I've updated the answer)

Answer (score 2):

super calls the functionality from your parent class.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.execute();
    }
}

interface Foo
{
    public void execute();
}

class A implements Foo
{
    public void execute()
    {
        System.out.println("from class A");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public void execute()
    {
        super.execute();
        System.out.println("from class B");
    }
}
```

The output of this code is

```
from class A
from class B
```

Comment: The new developer who write the execute method doesn't know that he should use super. This code will do the job, but it's not what I was asked to write.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon.

I'm mainly a .NET developer so don't be too sever with me, but I actually tried a sniplet in `C#` and did something like this:

**Input data we have**

```
 interface SomeInterface
 {
   void execute();
 }

public class A : SomeInterface
{
   public  void execute() {
      Console.WriteLine("Start process"); 
   }
}


public class B : A {

    public void  execute() {
        Console.WriteLine("Execute B");
    }
}
```

The thing is (and this *should* work in `Java` as well), that if I write a code, like this:

```
SomeInterface inter = new B(); 
inter.execute();
```

it will print as requested and expected "Start process", cause `inter.exexute` will call it's implemented version (so present in `A`) even if *actual* type is `B`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe in C#, you have to specifically say override in the method's signature, otherwise the default behavior is simply to "hide" the implementation.